# Insert and Update stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm new to stored procedures and SQL Server (currently using SQL Server 2016). I'm trying to create a stored procedure that will allow me to set a nickname to a specific account. Based on the `MemberAccountNicknameId` that they've passed I want to know whether to update an existing row, or if null, then add a new row. I am unfamiliar with how to go about this.

```
USE [MemberRelations]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspSetAccountNickname] 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @CrmID varchar(20),
            @AccountNumber varchar(20),
            @Nickname varchar(50),
            @CreatedDate datetime,
            @updatedDate datetime

    SELECT

     if (@MemberAccountNicknameId is NULL)
        INSERT INTO MemberAccountNickname
        ELSE
        UPDATE MemberAccountNickname
        WHERE  MemberAccountNicknameId = @MemberAccountNicknameId
END
```

`MemberAccountNicknameId` is what I called my primary key in the table. Hope this helps and let me know if I need to include anything else.

Thank you,

Comment: Study:  https://michaeljswart.com/2017/07/sql-server-upsert-patterns-and-antipatterns/

Comment: So skip the procedure usage and just write a simple tsql script that uses a variable (where is it? you did not declare it anywhere) to hold a predefined value for this ID column. You then check for existence in the table and then update (if found) or insert. This is basic tsql which you need to master before you write anything more complicated. Learn to walk before you try to run.

Comment: There is a lot of invalid syntax in this as well. As @SMor said try and make it work as tsql first. It will probably make the errors more obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [Merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) operation in SQL Server, they have an example of what you want.